# Python get unix time rounded to a minute

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm inserting a bunch of data to sql database that also has timestamp attribute (accepting only `INTEGER` to save space).

There are always a bunch of data being inserted at once and they are not gonna take more than a few seconds to insert. The timestamp is only used as an indicator as to when was the last time the data was updated, and to fetch the last data (`GROUP BY timestamp`).

What is the most efficient way round the timestamp to the nearest minute?

One (I guess very inefficient) way would be:

Edit:

```
from time import time

def getTime():
    ts = time()
    return ts - ts & 60
```

Comment: Why do you need "the most efficient" way? Do you anticipate that rounding will take a lot of time in your app?

Comment: No, but I anticipate to go through tens of thousands of rows of data and so want to make sure that it stays within that 1 min boundary, it's also good practise in case the app needs to be scaled up in future.

Comment: Rob's answer has `ts % 60` **not** `ts & 60`. The `&` operator is bitwise AND; it's not going to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Round the timestamps before you do the insert, like so:

```
rounded_ts = ts - (ts % 60)
cur.execute("insert into .... ? ...", (... rounded_ts, ...)")
```

I have no idea is this the most efficient, but since it only takes 60ns on my PC, I don't think finding a more efficient method will save much:

```
In [11]: %timeit rounded_ts = ts - (ts % 60)
10000000 loops, best of 3: 61.3 ns per loop
```

Comment: Edited OP to include the code, please have a look if that's correct.

Comment: OP wants the time rounded to the nearest minute, not rounded down.

Comment: 2Ring thanks for pointing that out, and yes, you are right. This would effectively give me 30 seconds instead of 60 seconds in worst case for the script to process the data.